# How to Client initialization , socket.io namespaces

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, routes, socket.io, namespaces

The initialization of namespaces in the client(unity) cannot be done and an error occurs, please help

```
public SocketIOUnity socket;

void Start()
{
var uri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.5:11100");
socket = new SocketIOUnity(uri, new SocketIOOptions
{
Transport = SocketIOClient.Transport.TransportProtocol.WebSocket
});
socket.JsonSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer();

    socket.OnConnected += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Debug.Print("socket.OnConnected");
    };

    socket.OnDisconnected += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Debug.Print("disconnect: " + e);
    };

    socket.Connect();

    var nsp = socket("/my-namespace");
}
```

It is possible to do this by creating a new connection, but it's silly (a new connection must be created for each namespace!)

```
public SocketIOUnity socket;
public SocketIOUnity nsp;

void Start()
{
    var uri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.5:11100");
    socket = new SocketIOUnity(uri, new SocketIOOptions
    {
        Transport = SocketIOClient.Transport.TransportProtocol.WebSocket
    });
    socket.JsonSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer();

    socket.OnConnected += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Debug.Print("socket.OnConnected");
    };

    socket.OnDisconnected += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Debug.Print("disconnect: " + e);
    };

    socket.Connect();


    nsp = new SocketIOUnity("http://192.168.1.5:11100/my-namespace", new SocketIOOptions
    { });

    nsp.OnConnected += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Debug.Print("socket.OnConnected");
    };

    nsp.OnDisconnected += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Debug.Print("disconnect: " + e);
    };
    nsp.Connect();

}
```

How to do this without creating a new connection?

Comment: "an error occurs" please share the error message.

Comment: Assets\Scripts\Server.cs(67,19): error CS1955: Non-invocable member 'Server.socket' cannot be used like a method. @nilsK

Comment: What library are you using? Do you use [Socket.IO for Unity with namespaces](https://github.com/j-be/unity-socket.io-with-namespace) ?

Comment: And can you show the script that error is coming from? Doesn't seem related to the code you show

Comment: In the first script I posted, I try to initialize the client the way the SocketIO site explains, which gives an error. @derHugo

Comment: Description link https://socket.io/docs/v4/namespaces/

Comment: I use this library https://github.com/itisnajim/SocketIOUnity

Comment: ` var nsp = socket("/my-namespace"); ` it has error

Comment: The code examples on socket.io are not in c# but as far as I can tell JavaScript .. and as said the other link I posted is a fork of that repo as well but with support of namespaces ..